How to solve ODE, $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{-(v^2-4900)}{500}$
Solve the following ODE, expressing v in terms of t. It is given that when t = 0, v = 0;
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{-(v^2-4900)}{500}$$
I have tried manipulating the fraction, which resulted in $$t = -500∫\frac{1}{(v-70)(v+70)}dv$$
However, if I try to solve this integral, it would result in
$$t =500(\frac{1}{140}\ln \left|v-70\right|-\frac{1}{140}\ln \left|v+70\right|+C)$$
This would make it difficult to isolate v, which is needed as the second part of the question requires me to find
$$\lim_{t \to ∞} v$$
Any help would be appreciated

Your third equation is incorrect. Probably you lost a $-$ sign along the way.

The expression for $t$ should be (possibly a mistake in the partial fraction decomposition) $$t =\frac{500}{140}\ln \left|v+70\right|-\frac{500}{140}\ln \left|v-70\right|+C$$
Using that $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(x/y)$ we get $$t-C=\dfrac{500}{140}\ln\left(\dfrac{|v+70|}{|v-70|}\right)\implies e^{\frac{140}{500}(t-C)}=\dfrac{|v+70|}{|v-70|}$$
From the initial condition $t=0, v=0$ we find $C=0$.
As $v=0$ in some neighbourhood $\dfrac{|v+70|}{|v-70|}=\dfrac{70+v}{70-v}$. We can now express $v$ in terms of $t$:
$$e^{\frac{140}{500}t}=\dfrac{70+v}{70-v}\implies v(e^{\frac{140}{500}t}+1)=70(e^{\frac{140}{500}t}-1)\implies v=\dfrac{70(e^{\frac{140}{500}t}-1)}{1+e^{\frac{140}{500}t}}=\dfrac{70(e^{\frac{7}{25}t}-1)}{1+e^{\frac{7}{25}t}}$$
It is now obvious that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty} v(t)=70$.

I have a small question about this part. as $v=0$ in some neighbourhood $\dfrac{|v+70|}{|v-70|}=\dfrac{70+v}{70-v}$. How can we be sure that $v < 70$ holds as $t \rightarrow \infty$. If this is a silly question, I apologize.

This is because the equation is autonomous (it does not depend on $t$) and orbits cannot intersect on autonomous equations.

First factorize $\frac{1}{140}$ out and multiply both sides by $\frac{140}{500}$, yielding:
$$\ln|v-70| - \ln|v+70| = -\frac{140}{500}t + 140C$$
Then, by logarithm properties:
$$\ln\left|\frac{v-70}{v+70}\right| = -\frac{7}{25}t + 140C$$
Exponentiating both sides and applying absolute value rules:
$$\frac{v-70}{v+70} = \pm e^{140C}e^{-\frac{7}{25}t}$$
Now you can easily solve for $v$ and find $\lim_{t\to \infty} v(t).$

You can write
\begin{equation}
t = \frac{50}{14}(\ln|v - 70| - \ln|v + 70| + C) \implies 0.28t =  \ln(\left|\frac{v-70}{v+70}\right|)+C
\end{equation}
Since $V(0)=0$, therefore $C=0$ and we have
\begin{equation}
 0.28t=  \ln(\left|\frac{v-70}{v+70}\right|) \implies \frac{v-70}{v+70}=e^{0.28t} \implies v(t)=\frac{140}{-e^{0.28t}+1}-70
\end{equation}
hence $\lim_{t \to \infty} v(t)=70$.

Re-arrangement gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
d t & =-\frac{500}{v^2-4900} d v \\
\Rightarrow \quad  \int d t & =-500 \int \frac{d v}{v^2-4900} \\
& =-500 \int\left(\frac{1}{v-70}-\frac{1}{v+70}\right) d t \\
\therefore\quad t & =-\frac{25}{7} \ln \left|\frac{v-70}{v+70}\right|+C \\
\end{aligned}
$$
As $t=0=v \Rightarrow C=0$, we have $$
\frac{v-70}{v+70}= \pm e^{-\frac{7}{25} t}
$$
As $t\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{v-70}{v+70} \rightarrow 0$ and hence
$$\boxed{\lim_{t \to \infty} v=70}$$
